# How to properly type this kind of pattern?

Tags: typescript

I've written some code that follows this kind of pattern:

- An endpoint receives some data that can be one of several pre-defined object types. For example, let's say we have three different objects called Contact, Connection, and Friend. Each one of these objects has completely different structures, but similar logic needs to be done on each that transform the data into the same kind of output. So, I've written three different functions like this:

```
const transformContact = (data: Contact): Record<string, any> => {return {name: "mike", id: 123}};
const transformConnection = (data: Connection): Record<string, any> => {return {name: "alex", id: 124}}
const transformFriend = (data: Friend): Record<string, any> => {return {name: "sarah", id: 125}}

interface Contact {
  name: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}

interface Connection {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  cellNumber: string;
}

interface Friend {
  address: string;
  nickname: string;
}
```

And then I have a function that returns a transform function to use in the rest of the endpoint, so that I don't have to do checks based on the input for the rest of the code:

```
type ObjectType = 'Contact' | 'Connection' | 'Friend';

export const getDocFunction = (type: ObjectType): ReturnType => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'Contact':
      return transformContact;
    case 'Connection':
      return transformConnection;
    case 'Friend':
      return transformFriend;
  }
}
```

I've made `ReturnType` like this:

```
type ReturnType = 
((data: Contact) => Record<string, any>) |
((data: Connection) => Record<string, any>) |
((data: Friend) => Record<string, any>)
```

Now, in my endpoint, when I receive some data, I know it's either of type Contact OR Connection, OR Friend

```
type Data = Contact | Connection | Friend;
```

But, when I call `getDocFunction`, the function it returns actually requires a type parameter like this:

```
type ActuallyNeeded = Contact & Connection & Friend;
```

I kind of understand this, because if the code says the data received is only one of the three possible types, but the function only accepts one specific type, errors are thrown. So it makes sense, but what I don't like is that the data being typed as a union of all three is simply not an accurate representation of the data.

It kinda of works for me because all I do in the endpoint code is just pass in the data to the transform function and I'm done with it. But if I do have to do more in the future, then the intellisense telling me that the data has properties of all three possible interfaces combined just doesn't seem quite right to me, because it will actually only adhere to one of those interfaces.

Do you have any suggestions to make this pattern cleaner or improve the typings in some way? Also, as a secondary question, does this type of pattern have a formal name? If so, I'd like to do some research on it.

EDIT: [Here is a ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAJYCcCGMBm4kFsDCVYVQEBeeACgBMVCAuefSQ4gSnoCUBTCJSgHjhIAlpADmAGnhoAngD54JeQG8knWAFckkeEsgpsnegCJsQgNacjkoZXoBGAEwBmAL4uA3GChxEqDFjwoSG5YISgFCmo6BiCQsMg2eC4efkERCSlIOQVlVQ0tHT0DYxQAG04ADyt4G3sHABY3LxgEZDRoTBwAMWFOSEoIqhoUeh6hPspE5KxU5HTJGXlFHTzNbV19Q3gjaBRUAAtq2vhHAFYm4BFYTiR0Ik4YpiIEJWB4eCKttLFPd4AHfZQTgAOXU2AARjd6N9RJ4XCArjc7qAHoxgsR4jo3vB0EIkHBgZtoXMftjSigCUT4DDfvAUaVSqCIVDqSTYcB4ZcmEj7vAxhMse8UJRKKpoNBicJSe9IEJQGZPpL0nCQLBpH8HgB5cEAKxCABV1Q8yAByRjMWAm%20AAH3gZtiGKgVttJv5-RNnmAlT%20WAQEBa8FEagAIuBQF11JBHdoyOQ1Rr6Nq9cRDRqpmo1qnjcpsdAAO5CWCgfYUeOcFiC950ikPe1PYgm2jYqvwVYFNr%20HDm56096gGt2tFxJ1NlvvNvaDsdAJD6O96vQWtuyiN5tVie%20dqdbDL2nwzllpIZrRZiLAchDaLd1g5I8pARshZZWQV63ny8jR7o0JQCvLaa8A%20UoZIsr7vlEn7Ln%208gAbMwFPnILCqka8DBsMETXggtqzj%202i2ruwCHgAgsQ6hlKU0jApwnCUDRGEEM88AAGRfsO2gsQRwAAPQAFR8fxAmCUJglcdxXHwAAohU%20h-OU8DgOg8DqNA6Q4pG0bQDUk77A8Ew%20lcID%20j4nAAG59KQOguFImkyPAXHiQAsmGZiqWgWkQKYYitpwACO6icD4sDgPAengAZRmtH407dOpERBrAobhupuHkKZ5kAHTguAlDSOlZYsJ6EWbp2BiUGhhARFO24RlGqVmUwmXZdIBUgPZ8DpR13k%20Ap8ClOAohykpKleR2240eVKBAA) with proper code:

Comment: Could you [edit] the code to be a [mre]?  I can see by looking at `const transformContact(data: Contact) => Record<string, any>` that it's invalid syntax and without the definitions of `Contact` etc it might be a hard slog trying to make suggestions that are testable.  If you could make the code example some plaintext that we could paste into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work on it, it would help a lot.

Comment: @jcalz Yep for sure, just edited and added in some more definitions. They are basically just basic interfaces with different keys. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! `const transformContact(data: Contact) => Record<string, any>` is still invalid syntax.  Maybe you could paste your own example code into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and modify it until there are no errors unrelated to the problem you're having, and then paste the resulting plaintext version back into the question.

Comment: You almost certainly want an overload, and not what you're currently doing.

Comment: TS playground linked and code updated. @JaredSmith could you explain that some more?

Comment: Hmm, can you show how you actually use `getDocFunction()`? Given the implementation I'd probably make it generic as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4j4aN), but without demonstrated use cases I can't be sure.

Comment: @jcalz Sure, updated the ts playground link

Comment: What you're dealing with is what I call *correlated union types* as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and there's a recommended type refactoring described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) which should work, as demonstrated in this [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxjo7w). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jerfp go with jcalz's solution.

Comment: @jcalz yes that looks great, thank you so much for the code to checkout and also for the reference github issue and pull request. I've checked them out and now going through them more thoroughly to try to really understand everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem you're having is that you have a single "event" object whose `body` is a `Contact`, `Connection`, or `Friend`, which also contains a `type` property which is one of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Contact"`, `"Connection"`, or `"Friend"`... but your data structure doesn't represent the *correlation* between those.  As far as the compiler knows, the event body could have a `type` of `"Friend"` but be a `Connection` type.  That is, it's dealing with two uncorrelated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types): `(Contact | Connection | Friend) & {type: "Contact" | "Connection" | "Friend"}`.

So when you look up a `docFunction` with `body.type`, you get one of the three possible functions, and then when you try to pass it the `body` as a parameter, the compiler worries that it's not safe.  "What if you're passing a `Connection` to something that turns out to be `transformFriend()`?"  The only thing it can be sure would be safe is if you were passing something which was a `Contact` *and* a `Connection` *and* a `Friend` to the function, because then it would work no matter what.  And that's why the error message complains that it can't be sure that your `Contact | Connection | Friend` is actually a `Contact & Connection & Friend`.

Indeed, that kind of error is usually the sort of thing that alerts me to the existence of this underlying issue with correlated unions.  At one point I filed an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) asking for some way to deal with these that's better than just giving up (e.g., using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to lie to the compiler).

---

Eventually, [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) was merged, which, among other things, describes a refactoring technique that uses [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to get better behavior.  The idea is to write out types explicitly as [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some set of keys, and [index into them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with one of these keys as a generic type parameter, so that the operation you want to support can be seen as a straightforward generic operation.

In your example code case, I'd probably do it like this:

---

First, build a type that represents a key-value mapping of your data in the simplest terms possible:

```
interface DataMap {
  Contact: Contact,
  Connection: Connection,
  Friend: Friend
}
```

Then, start giving types to things that explicitly map over this type:

```
const docFunction: { [K in keyof DataMap]: (data: DataMap[K]) => Record<string, any> } = {
  Contact: transformContact,
  Connection: transformConnection,
  Friend: transformFriend
}
export const getDocFunction = <K extends keyof DataMap>(type: K) => {
  return docFunction[type];
}
```

So `getDocFunction` takes a `type` of generic type `K` and returns a function of corresponding generic type `(data: DataMap[K]) => Record<string, any>` in a manner that *distributes* over unions in `K`.

Now let's describe the event `body` property as a similar distributive mapped type:

```
type Body<K extends keyof DataMap = keyof DataMap> =
  { [P in K]: { type: P } & DataMap[P] }[K];
```

You can hopefully convince yourself that, for example, `Body<"Contact">` is `{type: "Contact"} & Contact`, and that `Body<keyof DataMap>` is a *union* of the three types.

Finally, we can write a generic `processEvent()` function that takes a `Body<K>` and calls the right transform function:

```
function processEvent<K extends keyof DataMap>(event: { body: Body<K> }) {
  const transformFunc = getDocFunction(event.body.type);
  const transformedData = transformFunc(event.body);
  return transformedData;
}
```

That works because `transformFunc` is seen as being equivalent to type `(data: DataMap[K]) => Record<string, any>`, while `event.body` is assignable to `DataMap[K]`, so the function is known to accept `event.body`, and it compiles with no error.

And you can call `processEvent()` with any of the `Body` types (or even a union) and it will succeed:

```
processEvent({
  body: {
    type: "Contact",
    name: "abc",
    phoneNumber: "123"
  }
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAJYCcCGMBm4kFsDCVYVQEBeeACgBMVCAuefSQ4gSnoCUBTCJSgHjhIAlpADmAGnhoAngD54JeQG94STrACuSSPBWQU2TvQBE2IQGtOxyUMr0AjACYAzPAC+7gNxgocRKgwsPChIblghKAUKajoGELCIyDZ4Lh5+QREJKUg5BWVVdS0dPQMjeGMUABtOAA9reFsHRwAWd3cfGARkNGhMHAAxYU5ISiiqGhR6QaFhymTUrHTkTMkZeUVdAs1tTf1DE2gUVAALesb4JwBWNrcQEVhOJHQiTjimIgQlYHh4PbKMsTeH4AB2OUE4ADkNNgAEaPegA0TeW7Ae6PZ6gV6MULERK6b7wdBCJBwCGlBHLQEEyooUnk+CIoHwTGVSpQ2HwhmUpHAFFop4veDTWb4n4oSiUNTQaAU4RUn6QISgcx-WWZZEgVFMdGCgAiEwAsihgaK3sxYPRGObxATsQkoJb4rioDafsKRlMhiNeR0-JRwKB+hpIM7IPQVABtADSDR0lmk4HQ8H1hCNwIAuvRxrEUyg09H0yw8iluIsBNzVjl5B4yF8flaPvRuoEcA3iK63jjwg7-D0+sFIF3Eh33XZey3sKOfbVgVgEBBOvBROpdQGgyHuzoyHwY7UHiNoPB44nk4bjbJyLBpMCylGixs61sivB-YHg6GI1eb+mNcAv68ACFwEoaQd3gPdZkPY8k1zNMomg09U3PBQCUjAAFWN4CjTNNn-egMI8AAyRC82NCM0PTdwC28YB0HfTd4GBJAA04aUAFEADdhlgMCIIPI9OATGCz2BC9OC4phw3gGFgOkeggJAndqyLR8Fz8ZteiCddQCiZdYFXN8N0SchxO4gA6GSQLM-8WCZNSugCTScE4ShcyiDT+20kyJNgCzZNsgk1G2HQPKCFzc1-JiWPYnzyEfSy5NNH48PKNtYGsAkFXpCoYVADKfhBMFQnZOEkBMJxnGMAlbjcFggA)